# SSRS Domain name of owner changes after subscribing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have set up a SQL Reporting Services-server on a couple of VMs running on a physical server and I have encountered a strange problem. While setting up a subscription to a report the owner name will appear as expected, COMPUTER_NAME\USER_NAME but when editing the same subscription the domain name will have changed to something like WIN-XXXXXXXXX\USER_NAME. When setting up SSRS on other VMs running on the same physical computer the same happens, with the domain name being replaced with the same thing. It seems that somehow SSRS replaces the domain name with the name of the physical machine.

The VM itself is not on the domain, having only local administrator accounts which is the one owning the subscription. The account has been set up in SSRS with the appropriate permissions. The vm has not changed name since installing SSRS.

The problem is that SSRS won't recognize the new name so the scheduled reports won't run and I can't edit the schedules. After searching online I could only find one other person with the same problem and unfortunately no solution was suggested. Is there any way I force SSRS to use the machine name of the vm instead of the physical machine? Or if there's a workaround to the issue entirely?

Comment: Can you create a process by which all subscriptions are created by proxy using a low level local report user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a fix: It seems that only one user was affected by this weird behavior, creating a new user and adding it to the administrator-group worked.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your SSRS instance lives in a separate VM than your web application and is not set up under the same domain. As a workaround could you test this with mixed mode authentication and a local user account named 'LocalReportSubscriptionCreatorAccount'.

```
UPDATE
   Subscriptions 
SET 
   OwnerID = 'LocalReportSubscriptionCreatorAccount'
```